# ember / ember-data belongsTo and hasMany not updating as expected

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have two models:

```
App.Focusarea = DS.Model.extend
    definition: DS.attr('string')
    theme: DS.belongsTo('theme',
        async: true
    )

App.Theme = DS.Model.extend
    definition: DS.attr('string')
    focusareas: DS.hasMany('focusarea',
        async: true
    )
```

when creating one of each, I would like to associate the focus area to that theme

```
theme = store.createRecord("theme",
    id: 3
    definition: 'theme definition'
)

focusarea = store.createRecord("focusarea",
    id: 4
    definition: 'focusarea definition'
)

theme.get("focusareas").then (focusareas) ->
    focusareas.pushObject focusarea
    theme.save()
```

but when I run my tests

```
    theme.get('focusareas').then (focusareas)->
        expect(focusareas.toArray.length).to.equal(1)
```

it fails - the focusareas.toArray.length equals 0, in other words, the association failed. 
What am I doing wrong or what am I missing? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

**Update:**

Figured it out, theme.get('focusareas') returns an unresolved promise, which is 0, that when resolved will return 1 eg:

```
focusareas = theme.get('focusareas')
focusareas.then ->
    console.log focusareas.get('length') #=1
```

or

```
store.find('theme', 4).then (theme)->
    theme.get('focusareas').then ->
        expect(theme.get('focusareas').get('length')).to.equal(1)
```

in other words

```
store.find('theme', 4).then (theme)->
    theme.get('focusareas').then ->
        theme.get('focusareas').forEach (item) ->
            console.log(item.get('definition')) #'focusarea definition'
            item.get('theme').then ->
                console.log(item.get('theme').get('definition')) #'theme definition'
```

I guess I should just RTFM!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During object init you need to assign `focusareas` to some sort of collection that the getters and setters can work with . An `ArrayProxy` would work nicely in this case. How about even one you can sort items automagically with?

```
theme = store.createRecord("theme",
    id: 3
    definition: 'theme definition',
    focusareas: Ember.ArrayProxy.createWithMixins Ember.SortableMixin,
      content: [],
      sortProperties: ['id'], // Set this to any object property
      sortAscending: true
)
```

Hope that helped!

Comment: Excellent thanks for the tip Matthew. I figured it out as well, theme.get('focusareas') returns an unresolved promise, which is 0, that when resolved will return 1